# Comparing objects from two scopes to provide a value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I'll try to simplify the problem as much as I can.

Let's say I have 2 scopes

```
$scope.section1 = [
  {label: 'label1'},
  {label: 'label2'}
];

$scope.section2 = [
  {value: 'one'},
  {value: 'two}
];
```

Those scopes are used to generate buttons with ng-repeat

```
<button ng-repeat="item in section1 type="button">{{item.label}}</button>
```

and

```
<button ng-repeat="item in section2 type="button">{{item.value}}</button>
```

Now what I would like to do it to create a third scope that would attach values to the combinations of objects from the two previous ones, say:

```
$scope.combo = [
  { section1.label:label1 + section2.value: one = 'result1' },
  { section1.label:label2 + section2.value: one = 'result2' },
  { section1.label:label1 + section2.value: two = 'result3' },
  { section1.label:label2 + section2.value: two = 'result4' }
];
```

Now here comes the tricky part. What I would need to do, is to add a function that would take the values of clicked ng-repeat buttons from each section and then display the results based on the third scope in an input field or something.

So, if you click the button with label:label1 and the one with value:two the input field would show result3.

I'm very green when it comes to Angular and I have no idea how to approach it, especially that all values are strings.

Comment: BTW be careful with your terminology. You only have one scope and section1, section2 and combo are just arrays/objects created on that single scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could setup your combo something like ...

```
$scope.combo = {
    "label1": {
        "one": "result1",
        "two": "result2"
    },
    "label2": {
        "one": "result3",
        "two": "result4"
    }
}
```

You can then reference the correct value as combo[valueFromButton1][valueFromButton2] where valueFromButton1 and valueFromButton2 point at a model that contains the result of the clicked buttons. Your controller function then just needs to tie everything together by updating the model when the buttons are clicked.

See this plunkr ... https://embed.plnkr.co/GgorcM/

Comment: Works like a charm. And it's so simple :) Brilliant, thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Would it be possible to form results from 3 or more obects?

Comment: Yes, you just need to nest the results another level by converting the 'one' and 'two' values nested within combo to be an object representing the third set of  values.  This approach won't scale very easily and you may get to the point that Angular_10's approach would be easier to maintain due to its more linear approach. If you stick with my approach then you just need to append an extra [] accessor to pick out the result for the third level. HTH

Comment: Ha, I wasn't aware that you can nest even further, but that's good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing much you can also try like below provided code snippet.Run it to check the demo.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope' ,function($scope) {
    var key1, key2;
    $scope.click = function(type, item) {

        if (type == 'label') {
            key1 = item;
        } else if (type == 'val') {
            key2 = item;
        }

        $scope.key = key1 + '+' + key2;
        angular.forEach($scope.combo, function(val, key) {
          if(val[$scope.key]){
                $scope.finalVal = val[$scope.key];
          }
        });
    };

    $scope.section1 = [{
        label: 'label1'
    }, {
        label: 'label2'
    }];

    $scope.section2 = [{
        value: 'one'
    }, {
        value: 'two'
    }];

    $scope.combo = [{
        'label1+one': 'result1'
    }, {
        'label2+one': 'result2'
    }, {
        'label1+two': 'result3'
    }, {
        'label2+two': 'result4'
    }];

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='Ctrl'>

<button ng-repeat="item in section1" ng-click="click('label',item.label)" type="button">{{item.label}}</button>


<button ng-repeat="item in section2" ng-click="click('val',item.value)"type="button">{{item.value}}</button>
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="finalVal"/>{{key}} {{finalVal}}
  </div>
```